# Unable to convert the image outfit into separate meshes

Tags: mesh

In the below attachment , I want only the outfit(image) as separate meshes i.e jacket, bottoms, shoe etc.

I tried using the plugin [Image2Mesh](https://kjell.gumroad.com/l/i2m) [keI2M] plugin, it is able to convert complete image into mesh (i.e body and outfit into single mesh)

Let me know how to convert the outfit in the image to sperate meshes.
[image]

Comment: Your attachments are missing